# How to: At push/merge to master, commit/push specific files to another project

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks

When a user merges to master, merge those files to another project master the user doesn't have access to.  I'm giving non-technical users access to edit some config files, that I then push to production systems through saltstack.  which uses a different project on the same gitlab server for its configs.

I think i need a git hook setup on the initial project and that git hook would run a script to do the rest, but i'm not sure if this can be accomplished with git-cherrypick commands or deploy key.

The users are logging into gitlab and editing the file in the gitlab UI, which does a commit/merge request automatically, then an admin will complete the merge request/merge.

I then expect that I can take those files, copy them to my saltstack state /files/ directory where a highstate would run and push the config out to production servers. I'm just missing the automated mechanism to do so, I'm kind of a newb at git, and wonder if there is a git mechanism for this before I write a shitty bash script to accomplish it.

Comment: After further research, maybe what i want is similar to repository mirroring, but I don't want to mirror a complete repository, I just want to mirror a few files from one repo into a subdir of another repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a shell script from the CFEngine community (CFEngine is a configuration management tool) for pulling files out of VCS and then putting there where CFEngine server will pick them up and make them available to other CFEngine agents for distribution to hosts: https://github.com/cfengine/core/tree/master/contrib/masterfiles-stage 
In CFEngine terminology, "masterfiles" are the files being distributed from the source of truth.

You can look into triggering a pipeline job on another project (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html) but the user needs access rights to both projects.

Another possible option is git submodules (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Answer (score 1):

instead of copying them, why dont you use the gitlab project as a file-backend for saltstack?
Once someone approves a merge request, after 1 minute you can run a highstate with the new changes.
That bascially means that your salt-master has an connection to your gitlab project in which your config files (and saltstates) are stored. Its the same as using /srv/salt but only on gitlab. By doing so you could also use the benefits that git/gitlab provides in terms of version-control.
Take look at [this documentation](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/gitfs.html) if you want to set that up.

In terms of mirroring specific files between repos i guess you could try to use gitfs and build some sort of pipeline around that. (maybe with CI/CD)
You could also clone both repos and snyc them via rsync every minute.
For that a simple cron script could help. The script should pull repo1 on each execution, rsyncing everything to repo2 and pushing it to the remote.

I hope i could help.